# Access another device with different subnet

Tags: subnet

I setup my home network like in the image.

Router A network is more secure and Router B network is less secure.

How do I access the webgui of Router B from Device A1? I do not need any devices behind Router B to access any devices behind Router A.

I can't simply enter 10.0.0.1 in browser from Device A1. I hear static route is the solution but how? Any help is appreciated.

I posted this question in other forums and have received some responses but I still do not understand how to achieve my goal.

[image: My home network]

Comment: This is normally done with a single DNS server that can access all devices, if you made 192.168.2.1 the DNS server that should accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 2):

Disable NAT on both router A and B. Enable forwarding on the "modem" router, and add routes to `10.8.8.*/24` and `10.0.0*/24`.

This may not be easy to do with the firmware that is on home routers, but often you can install more flexible firmware (like OpenWRT).

You still may not be able to access the webgui of Router B if the webgui is protected and can only be accessed from the "client" LAN ports. Sometimes firmware has options to disable the protection.

---

Alternatively, use router A and B as switches, not as routers, then you'll have a single `192.168.2.*/24` everywhere, which will make everything a lot easier. This usually works by connecting the "modem" router cable to the "client" LAN ports instead of the "upstream" LAN ports, and disabling everything (e.g. DHCP) on router A and B.

---

> I posted this question in other forums and have received some responses but I still do not understand how to achieve my goal.

If you do not have it, reading up on some background in networking in general (broadcast domains, switch vs. router, routing) may help to understand the implications of the things you need to do.

There is no simple "just do this and you should be good" solution, you need to understand what is going on.